# Ceiling fan head scratcher

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan

I have a ceiling fan that's wired to two switches, one to control the fan and the other to control the light. Turn both on individually or together and all works well. Turn off fan from either switch or pull chain and the light goes out. But, the light might go out on the first time or the 10th time switch/pull chain is turned off. Pull chain for light twice(to turn light off and then on) and the light comes back on. Same goes for wall switch(turn off and back on), and the light will come back on. When I took the light kit off the fan and allowed it to just hang there, there were no issues with either wall switch or pull chain for fan cutting the light off. There is nothing that looks out of the ordinary with wiring inside the fan. But as soon as light kit is close to being put back on fan, the issue starts up again. What could be killing power to light when all wiring appears to be correct? What is it about the light kit just hanging and no issues arise?

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring in all boxes involved?

Comment: The only option I had today was to change the light kit. Upon completion of new light kit installation, no more issues! How strange is that! I have saved original light kit to bring home and test! But again, fan wall switch nor pull chain should have had any impact on light since they are wired separately!